# SVG and Canvas read SVG data differently

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I am attempting to write some JS which uses Canvas to emulate how SVG draws a shape on an image but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have some SVG data which draws a mouth on a face.

```
<svg id="svgTag" style="background: url('https://image.ibb.co/h9CWiR/odd_size.png') no-repeat " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="379.000000" height="540.000000" viewBox="0 0 379.000000 540.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,540.0000) scale(1.000000,-1.000000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
        <path d="M172 147
               c-21 -1 -69 -8 -74 -10
               l-2 -1 0 -32 0 -33 3 -4
               c9 -14 31 -36 44 -45
               12 -9 16 -11 27 -13
               2 -1 8 -2 12 -2
               9 -2 33 -3 34 -1
               0 1 1 1 2 1
               2 0 6 1 9 2
               16 5 29 14 47 32
               l9 8 0 44
               c0 33 0 43 -1 44 -4 3 -31 8 -49 10 -14 1 -44 1 -61 0
               z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have a fiddle of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/nhoughto5/5dhn1nm1/

I have written some javascript which takes the path data from the SVG element, parses it then uses Canvas methods to draw the same mouth. I've implemented a recursive solution to step through each command and draw it in exactly the same way.

```
 const commandString = /[\-0-9,. ]+/ig;
  const commandPattern = /[A-z]+/ig;
  const stringSplit = /[, ]+/ig;
  const shiftX = 0, shiftY = 0;

  function cleanArray(array) {
    const tmpArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].length > 0) {
        tmpArray.push(parseInt(array[i]));
      }
    }
    return tmpArray;
  }
  function move(array, context) {
    let x = array[0];
    let y = array[1];
    context.moveTo(x + shiftX, y + shiftY);
    //context.fill();
  }

  function quadraticTo(array, context) {
    let x = array[0];
    let y = array[1];
    let x1 = array[2];
    let y1 = array[3];
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x + shiftX, y + shiftY, x1 + shiftX, y1 + shiftY);
    context.fill();
    if (array.length > 4) {
      quadraticTo(array.splice(4, array.length), context);
    }
  }

  function lineTo(array, context) {
    let x = array[0];
    let y = array[1];
    context.lineTo(x + shiftX, y + shiftY);
    context.fill();
    if (array.length > 2) {
      lineTo(array.splice(2, array.length), context);
    }
  }

  function curveTo(array, context) {
    let x = array[0];
    let y = array[1];
    let x1 = array[2];
    let y1 = array[3];
    let x2 = array[4];
    let y2 = array[5];
    context.bezierCurveTo(x + shiftX, y + shiftY, x1 + shiftX, y1 + shiftY, x2 + shiftX, y2 + shiftY);
    context.fill();
    if (array.length > 6) {
      this._curveTo(array.splice(6, array.length), context);
    }
  }
  function draw(path, context){
    var commands = path.split(commandPattern);
    var commandArray = path.split(commandString);

    for (let i = 0, len = commandArray.length; i < len; i++) {
      let action = commandArray[i].toUpperCase();
      if (typeof commands[i] === 'undefined') break;

      const array = cleanArray(commands[i].split(stringSplit));
      switch (action) {
        case "M":
          move(array, context);
          break;
        case "C":
          curveTo(array, context);
          break;
        case "Q":
          quadraticTo(array, context);
          break;
        case "L":
          lineTo(array, context);
          break;
        case "Z":
          context.closePath();
          break;
        default:
      }
    }
  }
  function makeCanvas(canvas, ctx, img){
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgTag");
    var groups = svg.getElementsByTagName("g");
    var path = groups[0].childNodes[1].getAttribute("d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    console.log(path);
    draw(path, ctx);
  }
  function imageCanvas() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
      makeCanvas(c, ctx, img);
    }.bind(this), false);
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://image.ibb.co/h9CWiR/odd_size.png");

  }

  window.onload = imageCanvas();
```

Again, I have created a fiddle demonstrating this here:https://jsfiddle.net/nhoughto5/whwxtxcp/1/

The problem is that it seems completely wrong. At first I thought that it might be an issue with the translate value in the SVG group. I added a constant at the top of the JS to easily translate it around. If you modify the translate constants to: `const translateX = 100, translateY = 300;` what it draws will move into the middle and you can see that it is fantastically wrong.

I've stepped through my solution and checked that the data is being spliced and drawn onto the canvas in the correct order. Does canvas do something different to SVG that I'm not aware of? Not to toot my own horn but I'm fairly confident that my implementation is correct but there is something that I'm missing.

Comment: At first glance, you seem to have missed the distinction between absolute and relative commands in a path. Also I think you will have quite a few surprises when parsing real world SVG, the syntax is a lot nastier than it might seem.

Comment: @jcaron, I think you are right. Is there anyway to tell how the path is defined? I don't see anything obvious in the SVG itself.

Comment: @jcaron. Nvm, answered my own question ^. The documentation states: "All of the commands also come in two variants. An uppercase letter specifies absolute coordinates on the page, and a lowercase letter specifies relative coordinates (e.g. move from the last point 10px up and 7px to the left)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Setting the relative origin for Path2D

Your problem is that you are incorrectly setting the relative positions. Also you need to set the correct transform.

### Transform

The SVG transform is  `translate(0.000000,540.0000) scale(1.000000,-1.000000)`

Which is the equivalent to

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 540);
//               |         |  |  |
//              (x scale)  | (x  y  translate)
//                        (y scale)
```

### `d` Path

For the command "M x1 y1 c x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4 l x5 y5" where x,y represent coord pairs.

The equivalent canvas commands are

```
var ox = 0, oy = 0; // the relative origin
ox = X1; oy = Y1;
ctx.moveTo(ox, oy);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(ox + x2, oy + y2, ox + x3, oy + y3, ox = ox + x4, oy = oy + y4)
//                                                    ^^ new origin ^^ new origin
ctx.lineTo(ox = ox + x5, oy = ox + y5);
//         ^^ new origin ^^ new origin
```

Note that the last point for each segment is used to set the new relative origin

The code below is a modification of some of your snippet that correctly parses and executes the path commands.

```
// Only partial solution
// implement a subset of the 2D path string commands
const canvasPath = (()=>{
    var ctx, ox = 0, oy = 0;
    const [x, y] = [(p) => ox + p.shift(), (p) => oy + p.shift()];
    const X = (p) => p.shift(), Y = X;
    return {
        set context(ctx_) { ctx = ctx_ },
        c(p) { while(p.length > 0) { ctx.bezierCurveTo(x(p), y(p), x(p), y(p), ox = x(p), oy = y(p)) } },     
        q(p) { while(p.length > 0) { ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x(p), y(p), ox = x(p), oy = y(p)) } },        
        l(p) { while(p.length > 0) { ctx.lineTo(ox = x(p), oy = y(p)) } },
        z()  { ctx.closePath() },
        M(p) { ctx.moveTo(ox = X(p), oy = Y(p)) },
    };
})();


// This may throw for some paths as it cobers only some path commands 
function parsePath(path) {  
    var subPath, paths = [];
    path.replace(/([Mzlqc])|([\-0-9.]+)/g, s => {        
        if ("Mzlqc".indexOf(s) > -1) { paths.push(subPath = {type : s , points : []}) }
        else { subPath.points.push(Number(s)) }
        return s;
    });
    return paths;
}

// parses a path string and then adds that path to the canvas via canvasPath
function draw(path) {
    const subPaths = parsePath(path);
    for (const {type, points} of subPaths) { canvasPath[type](points) }
}

// Taken from OP snippet and modified to use above functions.
function makeCanvas(canvas, ctx, img) {
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgTag");
    var groups = svg.getElementsByTagName("g");
    var path = groups[0].childNodes[1].getAttribute("d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // NOTE image moved to 0,0

    // from SVG "translate(0.000000,540.0000) scale(1.000000,-1.000000)
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 540);    
    canvasPath.context = ctx;
    ctx.beginPath();
    draw(path);
    ctx.fill()
}
```

### Use `Path2D`

But that is a lot of hard work, and why do all that when you can use the [`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) object to do the work for you.

`Path2D` will accept a SVG path

```
const path = new Path2D(`M172 147
    c-21 -1 -69 -8 -74 -10
    l-2 -1 0 -32 0 -33 3 -4
    c9 -14 31 -36 44 -45 12 -9 16 -11 27 -13  2 -1 8 -2 12 -2  9 -2 33 -3 34 -1 0 1 
    1 1 2 1 2 0 6 1 9 2 16 5 29 14 47 32
    l9 8 0 44
    c0 33 0 43 -1 44 -4 3 -31 8 -49 10 -14 1 -44 1 -61 0 z`
);
```

You can render the path with the fill and stroke commands

```
ctx.fill(path);
ctx.stroke(path);
```

Thus your code is simplified to.

```
  function makeCanvas(canvas, ctx, img){
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgTag");
    var groups = svg.getElementsByTagName("g");
    var path = new Path2D(groups[0].childNodes[1].getAttribute("d"));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // NOTE image moved to 0,0 was 10,10
    // from SVG "translate(0.000000,540.0000) scale(1.000000,-1.000000)
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,-1,0,540);    
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fill(path);
  }
```

MDN is out of date `Path2D` is supported by Chrome and FireFox. Though you should check browser for compatibility as it is a recent addition.

Comment: And there are polyfills for browsers that don't support Path2d. e.g https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill contains one. And Path2d or polyfill will also allow the [`S` Bezier Curve command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) which if I'm not mistaken, as no built-in equivalent in CanvasContext2D API.

Comment: Oh but why do you say "*MDN is out of date `Path2D` is supported by Chrome and FireFox.*"?  They may well be out of date, but they do say it is supported in Chrome and FF and Edge and Safari10+.

Comment: @Kaiido The page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D last updated 26 Sep 2017 shows unknown support for Chrome and Opera  and Safari and does not include Edge.

Comment: Ah I see, the Constructor's page... Weird when we see that the [API's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D#Browser_compatibility) you linked to in your answer seems up to date, and that "*basic support*"  obviously includes the Constructor as it is the only way to access this API.